# How do I store and retrieve locations for google map into mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, google-maps

I'm sorry, I'm extremely new to google map, thus I need some help here.
I want to store and retrieve locations that I've input and display in the google map.

Any startup for me to get me going? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try Google Earth, it will save locations in kml, and and you can feed data to it from an external source. You can also place marks in Google maps if you are signed in. Other wise you didn't give enough information